# Unittest best practice for class methods that depend on each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I have a class like this:

```py
class ToDoList:
    def __init__():
        self._bullet_points: list[str] = []  # manages a simple list of strings
    
    def add_bullet_point(string: str):
        check_something(string)  # whatever, assume this is more complex
        self._bullet_points.append(string)

    def get_bullet_point(index: int):
        return self._bullet_points[index]

    def reverse_list():
        self._bullet_points = list(reversed(self._bullet_points))
```

Please note that its methods build up on each other, so I could not test "get_bullet_point" without having called "add_bullet_point" before.

Now I want to test every method of my class using unittests with pytest. I have made myself this fixture (= setup method):

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def todo_list():
    return ToDoList()
```

But how should I design the actual tests? What is best practice and what are pros and cons?

##### Approach 1: All in one (efficient, but not split into "units")

(Look at this short, effective and efficient piece of code!)

```py
def test_behavior(todo_list: ToDoList):
    test_string_1 = 'This is a test.'
    test_string_2 = 'This is another test.'
    todo_list.add_bullet_point(test_string_1)
    todo_list.add_bullet_point(test_string_2)
    assert test_string_1 == todo_list.get_bullet_point(0)
    assert test_string_2 == todo_list.get_bullet_point(1)
    todo_list.reverse_list()
    assert test_string_1 == todo_list.get_bullet_point(1)
    assert test_string_2 == todo_list.get_bullet_point(0)
```

##### Approach 2: Separate (inefficient, but split into "units")

(This is how I though it should be done - But do I really have to instanciate ToDoList 3 times and repeat the same code again and again?)

```py
def test_add_bullet_point(todo_list: ToDoList):
    test_string = 'This is a test.'
    todo_list.add_bullet_point(test_string)
    assert test_string == todo_list._bullet_points

def test_get_bullet_point(todo_list: ToDoList):
    test_string = 'This is a test.'
    todo_list.add_bullet_point(test_string)
    assert test_string == todo_list.get_bullet_point(0)

def test_reverse_list(todo_list: ToDoList):  # In this case, this happens to be the exact same as the all-in-one solution above
    test_string_1 = 'This is a test.'
    test_string_2 = 'This is another test.'
    todo_list.add_bullet_point(test_string_1)
    todo_list.add_bullet_point(test_string_2)
    assert test_string_1 == todo_list.get_bullet_point(0)
    assert test_string_2 == todo_list.get_bullet_point(1)
    todo_list.reverse_list()
    assert test_string_1 == todo_list.get_bullet_point(1)
    assert test_string_2 == todo_list.get_bullet_point(0)
```

##### Approach 3: Shared object (efficient AND split into "units")

(This needs the additional plugin "pytest-dependency", which leads to believe that this is not the common way to do it (?).)

First, change the fixture scope to "module" or "session":

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def todo_list():
    return ToDoList()
```

Then the tests:

```py
def test_add_bullet_point(todo_list: ToDoList):
    test_string = 'This is a test.'
    todo_list.add_bullet_point(test_string)
    assert test_string == todo_list._bullet_points

@pytest.mark.depends(on=['test_add_bullet_point'])
def test_get_bullet_point(todo_list: ToDoList):
    assert 'This is a test.' == todo_list.get_bullet_point(0)

@pytest.mark.depends(on=['test_get_bullet_point'])
def test_reverse_list(todo_list: ToDoList):
    todo_list.reverse_list()
    assert test_string_1 == todo_list.get_bullet_point(1)
    assert test_string_2 == todo_list.get_bullet_point(0)
```

##### Approach 4: Any other?

Comment: TBH I'd go with approach 1 to begin with; you can then split it if you need to.

Comment: Your methods are missing the `self` parameter. Please post code that are free of syntax errors.

Comment: These are module level functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recommend using non-public attributes in your tests, but that's outside of your question's scope. Therefore, I kept the first test case.

I'd prefer approach 2 with fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture
def todo_list() -> ToDoList:
    return ToDoList()

@pytest.fixture
def bullet_points() -> list[str]:
    return ["one", "two", "three"]

@pytest.fixture
def populated_list(todo_list: ToDoList, bullet_points: list[str]) -> ToDoList:
    for bullet_point in bullet_points:
        todo_list.add_bullet_point(bullet_point)
    return todo_list

def test_add_bullet_point(todo_list: ToDoList):
    test_string = 'This is a test.'
    todo_list.add_bullet_point(test_string)
    assert test_string == todo_list._bullet_points

def test_get_bullet_point(populated_list: ToDoList, bullet_points: list[str]):
    for i, bullet_point in enumerate(bullet_points):
        assert todo_list.get_bullet_point(i) == bullet_point

def test_reverse_list(populated_list: ToDoList, bullet_points: list[str]):
    populated_list.reverse_list()

    for i, bullet_point in enumerate(reversed(bullet_points)):
        assert populated_list.get_bullet_point(i) == bullet_point
```

`test_reverse_list` requires a populated todo_list to begin with. This setup can be extracted to a fixture. If you add more methods to your ToDoList, you'll probably need that fixture in a lot of tests. Additionally, you can parametrize the fixture if you want to test edge cases (only one item, multiple identical items, ...).

You can still use `@pytest.mark.depends` if the test cases take a long time and won't succeed anyway.

Using fixtures adds the additional benefit that pytest distinguishes between errors in a fixture and the actual test function in its output. If the fixture fails, pytest will annotate it with `ERROR` instead of `FAILED`.

Comment: Wow, the differentiation between fixture "errors" and "failed" tests is indeed a strong argument for how you solved it! (Definitely considering to accept this answer, but I'll keep the thread open to hear more potential answers for now)

Comment: One more question: Why is having a fixture just returning "ToDoList()" better than just creating ToDoList objects directly in the test functions?

Comment: @N.JonasFigge mainly because you already had that fixture in your question. But it still may be beneficial in the future: imagine you decide that a Todo list requires a name in its initializer. Most of your tests don't care about that name, but you'd have to change that line in every single test. Fixtures evolve over time while your code changes and you add tests. You shouldn't over engineer your fixtures, but anticipating common future problems doesn't hurt.

Comment: Two good reasons, i like the constructor modification argument! :) Thanks, accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I think you could add bullet points, bypassing the `add_bullet_points()` method, like this:

```py
def test_get_bullet_point()
    # Arrange
    todo_list = ToDoList()
    todo_list._bullet_points = ['test']

    # Act
    bp = todo_list.get_bullet_point(0)

    # Assert
    assert bp == 'test'
```

which decouples the method from your validation function.

Comment: This approach couples the test to the `_bullet_points` attribute. If it is renamed or changed to a different datatype, the class itself may still work as expected but the test will fail.

Comment: Okay, this is technically possible - but is it acceptable to reference protected variables in tests? (In addition to danzel's objection)

Comment: Both really good points - it's a bit of a work around and feels far less than ideal. I think @danzel's use of fixtures is much cleaner!